# How to select multiple individual table columns with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

Currently, my jQuery selector for selecting the 2nd and 7th column is:

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(2) span:contains('something'), table tr td:nth-child(7) span:contains('something')")
```

Is there a way to shorten this? It is bound to become a lot longer if I want to select more columns and `span:contains('something')` (which might even get longer, too) just keeps repeating itself.

Comment: It's just two selectors. I'm not sure how you'd expect to shorten it considering the actual code is only three characters. You might try https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @isherwood I'm sorry I don't understand why only three characters? The example is for columns 2 and 7. What if I need 2, 7, 13, 14, 18, 22, ...? It will get very repetitive then. I was thinking of something like `tr nth-child(2,7) span` or `tr nth-child(2)|nth-child(7) span`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write some jQuery helper function:

```js
jQuery.fn.tableColumnChildren = function(columnIndices, selector){

  const query = columnIndices.map(idx => `tr td:nth-child(${idx + 1}) ${selector}`).join(', ');
  return this.find(query);

};

const children = $('table').tableColumnChildren([0, 1], 'span:contains(something)');

console.log(children);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>test</td><td><span>something</span></td><td>more</td><tr>
<tr><td><span>something</span></td><td>cell test</td><td>data</td><tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @finefoot I didn't find any way to select exact column indices with `:nth-child`. Maybe we need some CSS expert here. I would do the way I proposed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: @finefoot there's no such thing as `td:nth-child(2,3,5)` - if that's what you was hoping for.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, that's exactly what I was hoping for. ;) Just like I wrote in my comment above (under the question itself). So I understand your comment to mean that there's no selector to do this easily. Isn't it a good alternative to do it like this answer proposes then? What's the alternative?

Comment: @finefoot i think your question and my answer are totally fine. there's no css selector to select individual column indices, so my solution is ok. and i don't see a better alternative right now. of course you can write it not as a jquery plugin function but just a standalone function with the first argument being the jquery table object. again if you're ok with my solution i'd ask you to vote up and accept my answer so i'd have motivation to support you in the future, thanks